# Question accepted - rep delay possible?

Tags: bug

Is there occasionally a delay in rep updates? My rep log shows a +2/-2 which should cancel out, but my net total is down 2.

[image]

I check the rep log in profile and it is inconsistent with the above info. The +2 is not updated. Might there be other factors at play, such as pending flag for duplicate or something?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how). Not all numbers are updated instantly and/or the pages are kept in the cache instead of fetching them every time from the database. Several scripts to update certain pages run at different intervals. Some scripts only run once a day.

So give it some time to catch up.

If you're really curious you can check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to get an accurate reputation count (that pages comes with data from the database when served).

[image: Caching]

Comment: How can you stay without clicking that green rep box for *soo* many days?!?

Comment: @BhargavRao Nobody told me I have to click that! What does it do?

Comment: It makes the green thing disappear :P

Comment: Why do I feel *deja vu* with this question... again?

Comment: Maybe I forgot to search for a dupe @Braiam?

Comment: Nah, I would blame brain caching D:

Comment: How could you make the first link in your answer anything except [this](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?